# Covariant derivative of maps on manifolds

Tags: geometry

Hi fellow mathematicians,

I learned about differential geometry in the past months. My research is on Mechanics and optimization. The topic is natural in modeling. My supervisor asked me if I could generalize the notion of quadratic functions in the Riemannian space. I accepted the challenge.

**Statement**: In a Euclidean space, we encounter our familiar quadratic functions, where the second derivative is constant, and the third derivative is null. In a Riemannian manifold, such functions do not exist, as the covariant third derivative cannot be null due to the incorporation of curvature in the formula.

**Question**: What is the generalized concept of a quadratic function in this context? What symmetries must the covariant third derivative of such a function possess to be regarded as the Riemannian counterpart of the concept of a quadratic function?

I know, given a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ equipped with a 2-form map called metric $g$ such that maps $T_p \mathcal{M} \otimes T_p \mathcal{M}$ into $\mathbb{R}$, we define a (smooth at first i.e. $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty$) function or map such that maps a point $p$ on manifold $\mathcal{M}$, addressed by position vector $X:=  x^i X_i$ in Einstein's notation through exponential map $\mbox{exp}_\mathcal{O} X$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

- The first covariant derivative of a scalar function $f$ is $\nabla_X f = Xf = f_* X = f^{; i} X_i$;
- The first covariant derivative $\nabla_X \nabla_X f = \nabla_X (f^{; i} X_i)$;

This is where I end up stuck. I thought, this could be $f^{; ij} X_i + f^{; i} \Gamma_{ij}^k X_k$, but the index $j$ does not become dummy... Therefore I come asking for help.

Comment: A "quadratic function" is a meaningless combination of two words unless one has a set of desired properties in mind. What properties would you like such functions to have?

Comment: This seems to be publishable material, my supervisor is very good at finding such. I edited the post statement.

Comment: OK, then require $\nabla \nabla \nabla f=0$. Publishable depends on what you can prove about such functions. Also, publishable where? Anything is publishable in **some** predatory journal.

Comment: Publishable on my fridge door. :)